# What to return from myfeeds.php (server side)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coldfusion, fullcalendar, coldfusion-9

I am returning the following string from my server side page (getEvents.cfm). I am working in ColdFusion.

```
[
{
    title: 'Event1',
    start: '2012-02-02',
    end: '2012-02-02',
    allDay: 'no'
},
{
    title: 'Event2',
    start: '2012-02-03',
    end: '2012-02-03',
    allDay: 'no'
}
]
```

But I get an error on page load 'there was an error while fetching events!'

Here is the code that I am using to fetch events:

```
eventSources: [

            // your event source
            {
                url: '../getevents.cfm',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    custom_param1: 'something',
                    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            }

            // any other sources...

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `allDay` should be true/false not no/yes. Second, the return string should look like this:

```
 [{
    "title": 'Event2',
    "start": '2012-02-03',
    "end": '2012-02-03',
    "allDay": 'false'
}]
```

Comment: Adil, yeah, don't forget that JSON objects have to have both the key and value enclosed in a string.
http://json.org/example.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I am new to jSon. I found the format at:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

May be they have provided the wrong jSon format.
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Yep - you need to quote the keys to preserve case sensitivity, otherwise ColdFusion uppercases them

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('path_to_your_json_file',function(data){
   $.each(data,function(index,entry){
      //assuming we already have a <div> created and get the id
         //show the JSON data
      $('#div_id_created_earlier').append('
         'Title: ' + entry.title + '<br \/>' + 
         'Start: ' + entry.start + '<br \/>' +
         'End: ' + entry.end + '<br \/>' +
         'All day: ' + entry.allDay + '<br \/><br \/>' +
      ');
   });
});
```